# Is there a standard convention for deciding when a probability is small enough to be 0%?

Tags: probability, statistics

If an event's probability is P(.000003). I think it is safe to say it has an approximately 0% chance of occurring. But is there a standard convention for deciding how many places a probabilities first significant digits is away from zero before we can officially say it is approximately 0%?

Comment: Yes, infinity ;-)

Comment: You use the integral over the relevant bit of the probability to define the probability.  If it's zero then the probability is 0 but that doesn't mean impossible.

Comment: A better question might be: 'when can we treat a really small probability *as if* it was just 0%?' (And maybe that is what you were asking, I am not sure). But to answer that question, I would say that it depends on what we use it for, and in particular what kinds of decisions we make on the basis of it, and how high the stakes are. E.g. For building a nuclear power plant I want the probability of something going wrong to be really, really, low, so I wouln't treat 0.00003 *as if* it was 0. But in other cases, like what is the chance of ending up with a bad hair cut, I would treat it as such.

Comment: I always be as precise as possible.. because .00000003 still has a chance of occurring, just very very very small. But 0 would imply it's not probable at all. Personally I would never round to completely 0 when dealing with probabilities. Unless if you had something like only 3 red balls in a box and asked what's the probability of pulling a blue ball. That's of course 0, assuming there's no magic occurring ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Suppose any newborn on earth would have $P(.000003)$ to be the inventor of cure for cancer, I think we will have a cure for cancer in a few decades.

However, if a coin flip has $P(.000003)$ chance to land on the side, I would say that a single coin flip chance to land on the side is approximately zero.

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

If the probability of an event is $=0.412738196\ldots$ then it is alright to say that it is "approximately $41\%$" or "approximately $40\%$". But in your case the exact probability is so near to $0$ that any reasonable approximation would have to be near $0.000003$ in *relative error* in order to make  sense. Therefore you'd have to say that the probability $p$ in question is "about $3$ in a million" in order to convey the proper impression.

If you talk about a probability of $0\%$ the uninformed reader might think that the probability is actually $=0$ (like the probability of hitting $\pi$ when shooting at the interval $[0,6]$). But if a nuclear plant will explode in 2017 with a probability of $0.000003$ one would have to think about whether to take that risk or not.